# Fn keys and sound not working after resume from deep suspend - ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, suspend, asus, acpi

I have recently bought an Asus Zenbook 14 UX425EA and promptly installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on dual boot with the preinstalled Windows 10. Everything has worked exceptionally well, except for this problem I encountered (or actually realised) the other day.

On a fresh boot, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys or hotkeys works well. I can adjust screen brightness, sound volume, disable trackpad etc. with the use of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>. I can even use <kbd>Fn</kbd> lock with <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and it works as it is expected.

After a suspension and resuming of the system, this functionality breaks. I can no longer use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> to utilize the features.

Using acpi_listen, I can see that before a suspension I receive a response when using <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>. After the suspension however, I get no response from the same combinations.

What can I do to fix this? Is there a resume scipt I can use to enable those keys? Can I unload and load a kernel module during suspension and resuming?

I am a newbie to Ubuntu, so I can't really find my way around this issue myself. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
[Picture of acpi_listen response when the Fn features are working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTx0c.png)

EDIT 2:
I discovered that also the sound stops working after the resume from sleep. Did not realize this before since I have not used any applications with sound up until now.

I also found out the above issue occur when using the deep sleep suspension. When using s2idle, there is no problem. However, this mode of suspension is not really as energy saving as it should be so its a poor option. Would be nice to have deep sleep enabled without this issue.

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround on pop-os, see :
https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2217
You need to enable modern standby (prob. with a kernel option) and disable Intel VMD controller in BIOS settings

Comment: Good suggestion but modern standby is not a proper replacement for deep sleep. It allows for the laptop to spin its fans for example. Not quite what you want when you put it in a bag for example.