# Debugging/fixing no sound and no Fn keys after deep suspend on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, suspend, asus, 21.10

I have Asus Zenbook UX325EA with Ubuntu 21.10 installed on it with kernel  version `5.13.0-21-generic`.

By default the sleep mode in the system was set to `s2idle`:

```
Aldea# cat /sys/power/mem_sleep            
[s2idle] deep
```

Since this discharges the battery quite fast when suspended, I have changed it to `deep` by doing this:

```
Aldea# echo 'deep' > /sys/power/mem_sleep
Aldea# cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle [deep]
```

However, after doing this and suspending the laptop, the sound and the Fn button are not working anymore. Rebooting fixes the problem. Also the problem doesn't exist if I leave the suspend mode to `s2idle`.

How do I fix or start debugging this?

This looks like a similar problem to this previous question, which was unanswered: [Fn keys and sound not working after resume from deep suspend - ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326292/fn-keys-and-sound-not-working-after-resume-from-deep-suspend-ubuntu-20-04-2-lt)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned below, the issue affects all linux distro at least from my tests on Zenbook UX425EA (tested on Pop OS 21.10, Ubunutu 21.10 and Nitrux 2.1.0 with newer kernel). I found a workaround on Pop OS 21.10 and a Zenbook UX425EA, see : https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/2217.

In short : You need to enable s2idle (modern standby) and disable Intel VMD controller in BIOS settings.

I had 15-20% battery drain overnight with modern standby. It's now 1-3% with Intel VMD controller disabled.

Comment: Hello. How does a solution on a non Ubuntu system help this question?

Comment: Hi. The issue affects all linux distro, at least from my tests on Zenbook UX425EA (tested on Pop OS 21.10, Ubunutu 21.10 and Nitrux 2.1.0 with newer kernel). Disabling Intel VMD controller in BIOS solves the high battery drain with s2idle. From 15-20% to 1-3% battery drain overnight, major gains !

Comment: It might be a good idea to add this info to your answer.

Comment: This is a fine suggestion and I upvoted your answer but s2idle aka s0 aka "modern standby" is not the same as proper suspend (s3). The modern version for example allows for fans to keep spinning(!).